# Remove leading zeros from string timestamp

Tags: lua, truncate, lua-patterns

Lua supports limited [Expressions](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1) and [Patterns](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html)

The time stamp is variable in the format DD:HH:MM:SS,FF (Days:Hours:Minutes:Seconds,Miliseconds)

The objective is to trim/truncate the timestamp by removing any leading zeros to represent as follow:

Example timestamps includes:

1. timestamp = 00:00:00:00,00 => 0
2. timestamp = 00:01:00:00,00 => 1:00:00,00
3. timestamp = 00:00:01:00,00 => 1:00,00
4. timestamp = 00:00:00:01,00 => 1,00
5. timestamp = 99:23:59:59,99 => 99:23:59:59,99

I am looking for a simple solution such as [using gsub](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CommonFunctions), TA

Comment: `gsub("^[0:]*","")` does it, except for 1.

Comment: This is actually very good.

Answer (score 1):

This regexp gets 5/5 but it is soo long

```
 local reg = '^[0]+[:]?[0]+[:]?[0]+[:]?[0]?'
    
    
    print('1 > ' .. '00:00:00:00,00 = ' .. ('00:00:00:00,00'):gsub(reg,''))
    print('2 > ' .. '00:01:00:00,00 = ' .. ('00:01:00:00,00'):gsub(reg,''))
    print('3 > ' .. '00:00:01:00,00 = ' .. ('00:00:01:00,00'):gsub(reg,''))
    print('4 > ' .. '00:00:00:01,00 = ' .. ('00:00:00:01,00'):gsub(reg,''))
    print('5 > ' .. '99:23:59:59,99 = ' .. ('99:23:59:59,99'):gsub(reg,''))
```

Comment: `'^0+:?0+:?0+:?0?'` works just fine

Comment: what's the problem with a long pattern if it gets the job done? I'm sure you have used more code to solve simpler problems in the past

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `string.match`? The below code is based on the assumption that the input will be a valid timestamp. It handles all five cases correctly, but I'm not sure whether trimming something like `00:00:00:00,42` to `42` - which this does - is desired.

```lua
local function trim_timestamp(timestamp)
    return timestamp:match"^[0:,]*(.+)$"
end
```

Otherwise, move the comma and the first digit of the seconds to the captured part:

```lua
local function trim_timestamp(timestamp)
    return timestamp:match"^[0:]*(%d,.+)$"
end
```

Note that this will then turn the first example into `0,00`; you'd have to explicitly handle the case of all zeroes:

```lua
local function trim_timestamp(timestamp)
    local trimmed = timestamp:match"^[0:]*(%d,.+)$"
    if trimmed == "0,00" then return "0" end -- shorten all zeroes
    return trimmed
end
```